# Sort records in a JS for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following piece of code. Based on the user's search date criteria it will yield results below (Search Results Tampa...). It works fine but is there a way I can sort by "CODE" in descending order while keeping the "CODE" date in tact? Basically I want "Date: 9/4/2014 Highest Probability of the Day: 47%" to be the first record and so on. Also, I tried .sort and it seems to think 16 is less than 2, which I'm guessing due to it being an array? Thank you.

```
    function showResults (results) {
            var resultItems = [];
            var resultCount = results.features.length;

            if (resultCount == 0){
                resultItems.push("<p class='reportHeader_font'><b>No data available for this location during the specified date(s).</b></p><br>");
            }
            else {
                resultItems.push("<p class='reportHeader_fontSemiBig'><b>Search Results</b></p>");
                resultItems.push("<p class='reportHeader_font'><b>" + addressText + "</b></p><br>");
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
                var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;


                if (attr = "DATE_VAL"){
                        attr1 = "Date"
                        var dateVal = "/Date(" + featureAttributes[attr] + ")/"
                        var date = new Date( parseFloat( dateVal.substr(6 ))).addHours(8);

                        // Add one day also because the above formula is for midnight GMT which is 6PM of the previous day.
                        resultDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear()
                        resultItems.push("<b>" + attr1 + ":</b>  " + resultDate + "<br>");

                }
                if (attr = "CODE"){
                        attr1 = "Highest Probability of the Day"
                        resultItems.push("<b>" + attr1 + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr]*10 + "%" + "<br>");
                }

            resultItems.push("<br>");

            }
            dom.byId("info").innerHTML = resultItems.join("");
            // Remove the Searching... after the query completes
            document.getElementById('wait').innerHTML = "";

        }
```

Search Results
Tampa, Florida, United States

Date: 9/1/2014
Highest Probability of the Day: 19%

Date: 9/2/2014
Highest Probability of the Day: 27%

Date: 9/3/2014
Highest Probability of the Day: 21%

Date: 9/4/2014
Highest Probability of the Day: 47%

Date: 9/6/2014
Highest Probability of the Day: 37%

Comment: 16 *is* greater than 2.

Comment: Ah! Sorry I meant less than. Will fix

Comment: It looks like you are comparing strings ("1" comes before "2") instead of numbers (or, more properly, dates).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following as the first line of your `showResults` function:

```
results.features.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.attributes.CODE - b.attributes.CODE;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it in ascending order. However I changed it to "return b.attributes.CODE - a.attributes.CODE;" in order to change it to descending order and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you thought about taking advantage of an external library.
Underscore has some really nice helper functions for sorting, filtering.

http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

You could also look at indexBy from underscore.js

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.indexBy(stooges, 'age');
=> {
  "40": {name: 'moe', age: 40},
  "50": {name: 'larry', age: 50},
  "60": {name: 'curly', age: 60}
}
```

you could seperate some concerns and indexBy your array by percantage and after that bind it to some html